SignalR Error - StreamBindingFailureMessage
I keep hitting this error when developing a Client for a SignalR app:

Unexpected message type: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.StreamBindingFailureMessage

What's the cause and how do I fix it?

Note: Answering myself to help others, including myself in the future.
This can happen easily particularly in development. Say we have a basic setup like this:
var stream = connection.StreamAsync<TestSample>(hubName, CancellationToken.None);

If you change the TestSample class, for example inherit from a base class:
public class TestSample //: RealTimeEvent

Or change the DTO's structure from what the publisher is providing then you will get this error. You need to match the class the publisher provides to what the subscriber binds.
